# Complexity of DFS : O(m)

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs

We say that dfs runs in $O(n+m)$ . For any connected graph $m \geq n-1 $.
Therefore :
$$m \geq n-1 \implies O(n+m) = O(m)$$

Do you agree ? Because, I have seen in many algorithms proofs this bound $O(n+m)$ but most of the times we are dealing with connected graphs .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's true for an undirected connected graph, but:

- sometimes, the undirected graph isn't connected;
- sometimes, it's a directed graph, and not all vertices are reachable from the starting vertex.

So $\mathcal{O}(n + m)$ (assuming $n = |V|$ and $m = |E|$ for a graph $G = (V, E)$) is always right, whereas $\mathcal{O}(m)$ is sometimes wrong.

Comment: thank you pretty clear